# Create QVD File using tool

Tags: qlikview

How can I create qvd file using Qlikview, or using an other tool
and how can i use qlikview using that file

Comment: Uh... start reading the docs? What is exactly the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
STORE YourTable into QvdName.qvd;
```

Comment: Yes when Load that qvd, it's not working ! ? I did load *  from [C:\\Repository\DEV.qvd](qvd)

Comment: What error message do you get? Your path seem to have an extra "\".

Try using LOAD * FROM [C:\Repository\DEV.qvd](qvd);

You can always use the button "Table Files..." located in the bottom right side in the script editor and browse to your qvd.

Comment: @NinaPRO instead of trying to code it directly, try using the UI - in the data tab at the bottom, click table files and navigate to the file you want - this will generate the correct script and location